# Irresponsible votes to close

Tags: discussion

There are three votes to close [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318001/how-do-i-compute-cos-and-sin-in-a-given-interval-if-i-know-tan).

My questions regarding this are:

1. Is there some way of stating a reason to vote to close, or of finding out what someone's reason was, or of finding out who voted to close so that one can ask why they did so?
2. And, is there some way of voting against a proposed closure?

It's being suggested in comments that someone other than the original poster edited the question in a way that made it appear impolite.  If so, apparently that can be done without anyone even having any way for others to contact the person responsible to tell them they shouldn't do that.

**LATER EDIT:** I'm adding this in the interests of clarity.

The original post read as follows:

BEGIN QUOTE

tan(x)=-(2/3), (5pi)/2

This much I understand but now I'm supposed to count the two none written functionvalues in cos(x), sin(x) and tan(x) and I don't get anything.

END QUOTE

I **don't** think a reasonable reader *could* conclude based on that, that's it's not a real question.  "Cardinal" considers it obvious that a reasonable reader could conclude that.

Comment: I voted to close *this* question as not constructive, because calling users preemptively "imbecilic" is no way to start a constructive discussion. But no, you can't find out who voted unless they tell you or the question gets actually closed. You can vote to reopen afterwards, but do nothing in the meantime.

Comment: I suspect the question you linked to is _too localized_. Also give the fact that the question is pretty basic and reads like homework, I wouldn't be surprised if it were a near duplicate, although I did not check.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker, I believe you can see members who close voted using the 'Review' mechanism (at least you can on the stats SE). I don't think you can see who close voted "the old fashioned way" unless the question is closed.

Comment: @Macro I don't see that here. How would you do tha on stats SE. For completeness: One can usually see the first person to suggest a certain question to be duplicate, but this does not apply here.

Comment: @MichaelG, on the stats SE, you go to the review tab at the top, near your user name. I think this tab is only available after a certain reputation level. Click on close votes, then click on history. This only shows close votes done through the review mechanism, though, not those done by clicking 'close' on the question. It also shows votes to 'Leave Open' (which I don't think actually have any effect). Regarding the duplicates, the system automatically posts a comment in your name linking to the suspected duplicate, but you are free to delete that comment if you wish to remain anonymous.

Comment: @Macro Thanx, that seems to work here too.

Comment: @Macro: Comparing this sequence of clicks on the two sites for myself seems to suggest that the full history is only available to 10K+ users. At less than 10K you only see your own.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: +1. That's why I hate suggested edits that remove OP's voice, instead replacing them by the mollified one of a (well-meaning, but misguided) user suggesting the edit. I habitually decline such suggested edits from my end.

Comment: @gnometorule: I upvoted Michael's comment as well. In *this* instance, the mollifier was applied for the benefit of the *OP*; **not** for the benefit of the readers. I have a sometimes overly strong urge to give people the benefit of the doubt (even when repeatedly tested) and some people learn best through examples. :-)

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker(2): I only now clicked the question. It actually came on my review table, and I already had written my explanation for declining it, but when hitting the 'decline' button got the feedback 'already approved.' I don't know how to roll back, but kept it there. I scratched my head why people allowed this.

Comment: @cardinal: It's obviously case by case. Someone struggling with English might well deserve a little help, but it seems we both agree that this particular question looked like spit out on paper - pretty insulting (to me at least). :)

Comment: @gnometorule: To be clear: Are we talking about *this* question on meta or the one linked to by the OP? :-)

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker : I did not _preemptively_ call anyone imbecilic.  I did so _after_ observing their behavior.  How can someone who acts anonymously without stating reasons object to having their actions called imbecilic, dishonest, irresponsible, evil, or anything else, or feel that there's any incivility in that?

Comment: @cardinal: :) let me think..,

Comment: @MichaelHardy: *How can someone who acts anonymously without stating reasons object to having their actions called imbecilic, dishonest, irresponsible, evil, or anything else, or feel that there's any incivility in that?* With all due respect, most actions on this website are, by design, taken "anonymously without stating reasons"!

Comment: @cardinal : Indeed.  That is built-in incivility.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: +1 for your question too though, in particular part 1 (it seems to me 2 can be addressed easier by voting to reopen after). If this existed, this while discussion might not have happened. I assume that, as voting to close is no fun job (at least wouldn't be to me), some people dont want the process made more difficult; but your question I found perfectly legit.

Comment: @gnometorule:  Which version of the question did you find insulting?

Comment: @TaraB: The very first one was an absolute joke. I think there might have been editing over time, not only one edit, so I lost track. But if you can go back to the original submission, it looked like spit out.

Comment: @gnometorule:  The very first one was better than the next, in my opinion.  But what I didn't realise until just now was that the edit into the imperative was actually done by the OP, not the user I complained to about it!  So I'll have to go back and apologise now.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: So you place a comment every time you vote a post up or down? The arithmetic would seem to suggest otherwise.

Comment: @cardinal:  Up- and down-votes are quite different from votes to close.

Comment: @gnometorule: I disagree.  In this case it's not serious, but if harm results as a direct consequence of one's actions, then I don't think that the fact that one was _trying_ to do good absolves one from any blame.  But that's getting off topic!

Comment: @TaraB: I agree, somewhat, in principle, but not as regards the global condemnation made in Michael's prior comment. This site is geared around anonymous feedback. The fact that users provide it does not mean they (or their actions) should be subjected to *being called imbecilic, dishonest, irresponsible, evil, or anything else* solely for using the site as designed!

Comment: @cardinal:  They are very different in terms of anonymity levels, too.  Once a question is closed, the names of the close voters are actually publicly visible.  But I certainly don't agree with Michael's 'name-calling'.

Comment: @TaraB: I think the posting of the names of close voters is there *precisely* to provide some level of accountability to the community, which seems to me to be at odds with Michael's arguments thusfar.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: voting to close is not completely anonymous. If the question is closed, all those voting to close are noted. They can then be asked why.

Comment: @cardinal : Obviously I did not call anyone imbecilic or irresponsible because they used the site as designed, nor because of the mere fact that they voted to close without explaining.  I said that in this PARTICULAR case if there was no explanation, then the vote to close appeared imbecilic and irresponsible, because nothing in the content of the question itself explained it.

Comment: "Cardinal" changed the title of this question to "Unexplained votes to close", and I changed it back.  It was not simply the lack of explanation that I was referring to, but rather the fact that in this particular case, there seemed to be an irrationality about the votes to close that might conceivably be mitigated by some explanation.

Comment: Dear @MichaelHardy: I find the tone you are using in this entire discussion, including your word choice, unnecessarily combative. As I have pointed out to you below robjohn's answer, the "seeming irrationality" you are asserting seems quite dubious to me in light of the first few revisions to the question you have linked to. Perhaps instead of excoriating other users, you should consider looking carefully at the revision history and considering *all* of the possibilities. Cheers.

Comment: @cardinal You changed the title to significantly alter its tone, and you completely deleted a paragraph whose text you deemed combative. These actions (even though probably well intended), go against the [recommended edit policy,](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152533) which includes "clarifying meaning without changing it; always respect the original author".

Comment: Dear Bill (@MathGems): Yes, I did take that liberty with a very particular purpose in mind. As explained in my comments(!) and alluded to in the revision comments, I intended it as a hopefully useful example to the OP of a way they could reformulate the question in a tone more conducive to dialog. I have no issue with it being rolled back if the OP feels somehow slighted or prefers the original. Please **[recall](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/posts/4975/revisions)** that you have taken similar actions on less provocative wording of this same user's posts in the past.

Comment: @cardinal : You seem to be saying that my phrase "seeming irrationality" is _combative_.  How should I have phrased the idea that the votes to close appeared to be done for no reason?  If you think I'm mistaken in saying they appeared to be done for no reason, does that mean my statement that they appeared to have been done for no reason is _combative_, or does it merely mean that I'm too dumb to see the reasons that are so obvious to you?

Comment: @MichaelHardy: I have tried to make a *general* statement about the *general* tone that I perceive to be coming through in your question and subsequent comments. It is difficult for me to see how my comment could be misconstrued as somehow possibly intimating that you are "dumb". Furthermore, it is my opinion that the inflammatory rhetoric (*imbecilic*, *irresponsible*, *dishonest*, *evil*, *irrational*, *dumb*) being used strongly detracts from your question and the issue at hand. Cheers.

Comment: As regards how to ask such a question, why not simply say: *There are currently three votes to close on this question. Based on the current state of the question, I'm not seeing anything wrong with it. Can any of those that voted to close comment on their rationale?*

Comment: @cardinal, your comment is one of the few cases I have seen of one user attempting to intimidate another (if you are right, and if wrong, you are posting false accusations).

Comment: Just a remark: I got the question twice on my table (I believe as a first post, and for suggested edits), and I'm fairly certain that the *first* version actually read: <begin post> tan(x)=-(2/3), (5pi)/2 <end post>. I'm not doubting that this is what you found, but that is what I remember.

Comment: Titles, especially in the meta, should not be edited to alter the "tone".

Comment: @zyx: I find it hard to see how cardinal's most recent comment is intimidation, if Math Gems is Bill. So far, no moderators have made a publicly stated opinion about whether or not Math Gems is Bill (in their capacity as moderators; [Eric Naslund's comment here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3531/can-we-do-anything-to-avoid-losing-bill-d/3532#comment13153_3531) was made before he became a moderator), so please don't interpret this comment as being one - but I am just saying I don't see how it would be intimidation.

Comment: cardinal could easily have made the exact same points without making any explicit assertion about user identity (and the identities are totally immaterial for the present discussion).  One would have to be extremely or deliberately naive to not grasp why someone might suddenly purport to "out" a participant.  It's not to increase the chance of a full reply or to advance a discussion of the subject at hand.  If the accusation is false, that is another form of ugliness.

Comment: @ZevChonoles, see previous comment.  And you, a moderator, have made several snarky comments yourself about the same matter.  You certainly did express an opinion in public, the only thing that I cannot recall exactly (and have no interest in search-engining) is whether you made a specific and undeniable assertion that user A = user B.

Comment: @zyx: To call this particular post 'intimidation' is treating this incident like a legal courtcase, in the worst way. On the contrary, I found nothing objectionable in that particular post, as it struck me as one old-timer acknowledging another. On the contrary, to me *your* claim that it was, in fact, intimiation came across as an attempt to shut cardinal up; and if that is not the case, then here is one voice that it sounded to some that way. As well, terms such as "extremely or deliberately naive" and "ugliness" are not helping and hostile.

Comment: @zyx: If you insist on treating this like a laywer, then let me point out that you have just stated that everyone not agreeing with your opinion in this matter (a) *is* wrong ("extremely naive" expressing that only a fool could not see the truth you stated), and (b) is *not acting in good faith* ("deliberately naive" expressing he or she is aware of such truth, and chose to ignore it). Stated that way, I find it just a tad strong.

Comment: Disclaimer: As I got involved through my last two comments without wanting to, let me say that I too think that changing the title of MH's question was wrong and unfortunate.

Comment: Adverse comments that try to reach "behind the user profile" to identifiable, real, offline persons are the worst possible category of material on a mostly anonymous online web site, and I see no censorship (or legalistic) implication in highlighting and discouraging such attacks whenever they occur. This is one of many categories of material that are patently off-topic, but is much more noxious than most of the others.

Comment: @zyx: There's a difference between exposing an anonymous user, and exposing a suspended user (who claimed to be leaving the site anyway which is circumventing the suspension. One is indeed a breach of privacy and the other is a breach in the confidence the community gives to the users. If you have several accounts, one is suspended, and you are using the others actively it is a ground for their deletion, suspension, or otherwise. As indicated in a recent answer. If we do that to other users (e.g. WM), I don't see why this case is different.

Comment: @Asaf: If I had more unsuspended accounts I'd upvote that comment again and again!  ;-)  (Especially the last sentence.)

Comment: @Asaf, it is an egregious breach for this to be done *in public* to any *identifiable real person*.  It doesn't matter what policies, if any, are claimed to be violated.  Violations of the user policy can always be handled privately.  If people here had merely reported their speculations about user IDs to administrators, that would be unpleasant, but that is not the type of behavior I am criticizing.  Public speculations that "Asaf K is violating policy X!  He is user Y!" would be atrocious conduct on the meta.

Comment: @zyx User MathGems has publicly stated his relationship to Bill on a well known post. Neither he/she nor Bill have ever tried to clarify the issue after the assertian has been made that these are the same users. In case MathGems (who could clarify this by the way) has been wrongly accused to be Bill, he/she is probably flattered. And "Bill" is a very generic name. Nobody who googles his full name will end up at this post directly.

Comment: @Asaf In all fairness, it is not hard to undestand why all suckpuppets of WM get killed off immediately. Nothing good hasd has ever come from WM being here, his posts have less than zero value. But Bill did a good job in answering questions. Under the curent arrangement, he apparently can contribute in a positive way and easily get kicked off immediately if his other side shines through again...

Comment: @Michael: I'm not disagreeing. I'm just saying that on sites which are ultimately based on real people and real names, and often real life implications; anonymous users are second-class in some sense. And I don't think there's a real person called "Math Gems" anywhere.

Comment: @Asaf, the priority for real people/names and real life implications is exactly why comments that go behind the user profile and public behavior are extremely destructive for a site like this.  Nothing in the public material is sufficient to equate the two users and statements beyond the (already off-topic, speculative, and negative) claim that "in my opinion, X=Y" are vicious.

Comment: @zyx: I disagree with your last comment. I think there is a lot in the public space to equate these two particular users. I do agree that Bill's mathematical contribution has a lot of merits, it's his social skills and moderation which I saw problematic. If Math Gems and Bill are the same person, then the fact revealing himself will have devastating repercussions (deletions, extended suspensions, etc.) is making Bill behave much nicer to people and that's just fine.

Comment: @Asaf, you don't disagree that this is a case of attempted intimidation of users, you just like the result.  Your attitudes in relation to one particular user do not constitute a general principle for deciding whether that is acceptable use of the site as a whole.

Comment: @zyx: My preferences should not constitute of anything, except my preferences.

Comment: @Asaf: but they were presented in the context of a discussion on something else, and let's not confuse the two.  And you did formulate several policy-like general principles in the preceding comments.

Comment: re Michael Greinecker -- @cardinal has not disagreed, and Asaf just explained how, the comments that we are discussing apparently were used as a "conversation stopper", i.e., an attempt to limit communication by Math Gems by posting a particular form of intimidation.

Comment: Dear @zyx: Let me put this the most polite way possible: The
aspersions you have cast and the intent, motivations and maliciousness you have ascribed to me are *entirely and completely* baseless and patently false. They were also made without any attempt at all to seek clarification. Therefore, from my standpoint, they do not merit a response. That you would, furthermore, somehow conclude that my lack of response thusfar is indicative of some agreement with the injurious claims you have made is, quite frankly, contemptible. Cheers.

Comment: @cardinal, I did not draw any conclusions from your lack of response (and very little can be drawn from your present remarks, no matter how conclusory their tone). I pointed it out for the benefit of those commenters such as M.Greinecker who tried to use exactly this sort of nonresponse evidence in their arguments about the matter that you brought up. Having said that, I will emphasize again that you could and should have made whatever points you wished to without asserting any identity of users or other immaterial claims about persons.

Comment: @zyx: Apologies if the last sentence of my last comment is off-base. (It appears to be.) It did take several careful rereadings to parse correctly, but I can now see how your penultimate comment can be read in the way that you have just clarified it. Regards.

Comment: @cardinal, I don't have any objection to your preceding comment or its last sentence.  I phrased some, but certainly not all, of my comments in ways that are neutral as to possible *intentions*, so let me make it clear that this is not really the important point, and I should have avoided some of the controversy by being more careful in that respect.  The possibility of intimidation (or other destructive consequence) being a *result* of "piercing the user profile" is enough to put it at the top of the list of things to avoid on a site of this type.

Comment: This is also relevant to the subject of edits. I don't see anything particularly edit-worthy in this question and if it were up to me would keep colorful language (like "imbecilic") wherever possible.  But in the other edited question linked to by @cardinal, there was negative material naming an individual (and real-named) user which is a qualitatively different category of material.

Comment: Dear @zyx: It is probably not stated clearly enough in the comments, but the edit was a (in retrospect, feeble) attempt at providing the OP with one example of a more constructive version of the same question. I have to disagree regarding the "colorful" language in this instance. I think if we are going to use this space (meta) to solve real issues and improve the site, it's better to practice some professionalism, show a little more respect towards other users and give them (and their actions) more benefit of the doubt. That said, I wouldn't *normally* have edited this question, either.

Comment: However, I would (still) have downvoted and voted to close based on the nonconstructive tone. That is not to say I would want to take the "soul" out of meta (if it has one). You can see from some of my comments on other questions that I can appreciate some light (but respectful) banter, at times. (@zyx)

Comment: Other than changing question titles (good for mathematics questions on main site, bad on meta), in case of edits, as long as OP has final control it seems to be mainly a matter between OP and the editors.  For this question the colorful language contained enough qualifications to not really sting anyone (imo), but not everyone might agree. In addition to the professionalism axis there is a tolerance of user quirkiness axis, which correlates with the respect toward users and benefit of the doubt axes.  So if we have some posters who get more emotional (there are several) that is OK. (@cardinal)

Answer (score 6):

In cases like this, you can ask in comments why people voted to close. Otherwise, you need to wait and vote to reopen if it should become closed. As with all other voting, it often seems random and capricious. Serial downvoting can be detected and dealt with, but it is hard to catch and deal with all types of illogical voting.

Comment: Dear robjohn (and Michael Hardy): I invite you to look through the edit history of that question, particularly the first few. It does not seem at all implausible (much less *imbecilic*) to me that it might attract close votes. Cheers.

Comment: @cardinal: I did not mean to imply that I thought the votes on that post were illogical. I was saying that the only way to deal with the close votes was to vote to open if it should become closed. My comment about illogical voting was directed at general cases of random and capricious voting.

Comment: @cardinal : Can you explain _why_ such a question would attract votes to close?  Then your comment might be of some value.

Comment: Dear @MichaelHardy: Look at revision one. The close votes were as *not a real question*. It should be self-evident that a reasonable reader might arrive at such a conclusion. Cheers.

Comment: @cardinal : Returning to my question: How do you know that the close votes were as "not a real question"?  As you can see, that's a big part of what I asked in this present posting.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Because I clicked on the *close* link and the red box with the number 3 in it next to *not a real question* shows precisely that! :-)

Comment: @cardinal : You've lost me.  As far as I know, one can't click on the "close" link without voting to close, and I don't see any red box.  Is it possible for someone who does not vote to close the question to find out somehow that they were as "not a real question", if that's what they were?

Comment: @Michael: Go to the question, click on the *close(3)* link. This will pop up a window with five options on it, the fourth of which is *not a real question*. White numbers on red background next to each option will tell you how many votes to close of each type were made. For example, I have *not* voted to close this particular question, but I can see this information. You can close the window without voting to close by clicking on the X at top right.

Comment: @cardinal : The original post was as follows: BEGIN QUOTE: tan(x)=-(2/3), (5pi)/2

This much I understand but now I'm supposed to count the two none written functionvalues in cos(x), sin(x) and tan(x) and I don't get anything. END QUOTE You're claiming that it's "self-evident" that a reader would consider this "not a real question".  I don't think a reasonable reader could conclude based on that, that it's not a real question.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: I try to take reasonable care with my words; please consider them carefully. I said that it should be self-evident that a reasonable reader *might arrive at such a conclusion*. Regarding the snippet: No question is stated there, and, honestly, I can completely see how another user might conclude from it that: *[It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq#close).*

Answer (score 6):

*Is there some way of stating a reason to vote to close?*

**Yes.** The person voting to close can choose to [place a comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment) below the question indicating their reason.

*(...) or of finding out what someone's reason was?*

(Partial) **Yes**. You may [ask in comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment) for the rationale behind votes to close. However, the voter to close may not see this comment or may choose not to respond and even if they do respond, it may be suggested that the discussion be moved to meta or chat if it becomes even moderately protracted.

*(...) or of finding out who voted to close so that one can ask why they did so?*

(Partial) **Yes**. As indicated in the comments to this question, since you have (well) over 10K reputation, you may click on the *review* tab, then click on *Close Votes* then click on the *history* subtab at right. [This will show recent close votes](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/history) submitted *through the review panel*. I am not sure, but I do not believe it shows close votes submitted directly on the question page.

*And, is there some way of voting against a proposed closure?*

**Yes**. If the question ends up collecting the votes needed for closure, you may then vote to *[reopen](https://math.stackexchange.com/privileges/close-questions)* the question. This will also create an entry in the *review panel* to alert other users that they should revisit the post. Editing a closed post will have a similar effect.

*(...) someone other than the original poster edited the question in a way that made it appear impolite.  If so, apparently that can be done without anyone even having any way for others to contact the person responsible to tell them they shouldn't do that.*

**No**. Any of the editors can be [notified with the @username mechanism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) at any time. So, it *is (almost) always* possible to contact a post editor. Whether or not you should tell them "not to do that" is a matter of judgment. (Minor caveat: If two editors have the same user name or have the same user name as a commenter who commented after the edit, the editor may not be able to be notified.)

Comment: I did leave an @username comment to one of the editors, but I didn't feel confident that the user really would be notified, because their name didn't come up as a suggestion when I started typing, and it was a multiword name.

Comment: @TaraB: Yes, they'll be notified; but, no their name won't come up as a pop-up suggestion. :-) I think that's mentioned in the last link of my answer. The details and minutiae of commenting are convoluted and a bit murky. Cheers.

Comment: Ah, I just looked at the link now and it turns out I should have removed all the spaces in the username.  I think it may not work without the spaces removed.

Comment: Dear @TaraB: I think they probably *were* notified. As long as there is a match of at least the first *three* letters of a user name (unless something has changed since I last looked), the person will get notified. (See item (3) in that answer.)

Comment: You mean provided that person was somehow involved in the question or answer being commented on?

Comment: @TaraB: Correct. This includes *editing* as well. However, the names of editors don't show up in the suggestions tab when you're trying to notify them with a comment. They'll still be notified, though, provided your comment meets the specifications given at that answer I linked to detailing this. Like I alluded to before: convoluted and a bit murky. ;-)

Comment: Yes.  Okay, well thanks for the clarification.  It now turns out that I was attributing the edit to the wrong person, anyway!

Comment: @cardinal: at least on chat, it has been my experience that if two users have the same name, or the name of the one you want to contact is a prefix of another, then both get contacted. I don't know if the same applies to comments on posts. (This is assuming you type the whole name of the user you want to contact. If you type a common prefix, then all users associated with that post  with a name that matches will be contacted)

Comment: @robjohn: Thanks! That's interesting. I have only very limited experience with chat. I suppose if Michael G posts a comment under your answer, we could test that by notifying "Michael". Previously, my understanding was that only the *first* match of a prefix in reverse chronological order was taken. See, for example, item (4) at the last link I gave. :-)

Comment: @robjohn: Wow! Thanks for that edit. I'm glad you caught that (and not sure how I missed it). That was a terrible copy-paste attempt on my part! :-)